# Не происходит обновление GIT-репозитория в среде PHPStorm

Tags: git, phpstorm

PHPStorm не обновляет GIT-репозиторий. Операция обновления висит в процессах. Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой же проблемой.

[image]

Comment: да он там выполняет определенные завернутые команды. помогите ему через консоль

Comment: @VasyOk каким образом?

Comment: тут вам необходимо выучить команды git, это неизбежно)

я просто не совсем понию что вы там делаете, если вы с удаленного репозитория хотите получить изминения, отмените задачу в phpStorm и попробуйте
    git pull

Comment: @VasyOk вот **idea.log:** 09:43:46,817 [  86247]   INFO -   git4idea.commands.GitHandler - git fetch --progress --prune origin, если я сам руками начинаю вводить команду $ git fetch [имя удал. сервера], ШТОРМ выдает запрос на ввод пароля, (какой еще пароль...?)

Comment: а какой у Вас "удаленный сервер" - вот в этом и кроется ответ на вопрос "какой ещё пароль". Но Вы решили скрыть имя.

Answer (score 2):

Друзья, решение найдено!

Что было сделано:

1. Полностью очистить содержимое файла `C:\Users\[имя_пользователя]\.ssh\known_hosts`.
2. Выполнить команду [cоздания открытого SSH-ключа](http://git-scm.com/book/ru/ch4-3.html) через GitBash.
3. Перезапустить PhpStorm если был открыт.
4. Попробовать выполнить команды `Fetch` или `Pull`.